# Is there a simple way to explain required argument and optional argument? Python

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python through edX platform, I came across two terms that got me confused: required argument and optional argument.
Can anyone feel so kind to explain the difference between the two?

Take function round() for example,
the quiz stated: "The function round has two arguments. Select the two correct statements about these arguments."

here are the options:

number is a required argument.

number is an optional argument.

ndigits is a required argument.

ndigits is an optional argument.

According to what I have learned, I know that you have to specify input in order to get ndigit, such as round(1.68 , **1**) >>>>1.7

If I just wrote round(1.68) >>>> I will get 2

Thus, to my understanding, ndigit is an optional argument, meaning that you have to **choose** in order to make it work, otherwise, the function will only work what is it required, like an autopilot program

Please give me some feedback if I am wrong, or share some link where I can learn more.
I am not the native English speaker, so the words "required" and "optional" really seem confusing to me at one point. I hope to learn more from you all.

By the way, I got the right answer, I'll keep learning Python, hope to work in this field, cheers!

Comment: *optional* means you **can** specify but don't have to. *required* means that it won't work without it. Your summary is correct. To see that `number` is required, you need only consider what the logical result of rounding no number to the third digit -- it's nonsense! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for `round()` define the function as `round(number[, ndigits])`

The square brackets are common notation to show which arguments are optional.

In the case of `round()`, if the `ndigits` parameter is omitted or `None` it reverts to a predefined behaviour - in this case rounding to the nearest integer.

`number` on the other hand is required; the function cannot be called without this argument and will raise an error if it is missing.